# An example of ordered set based on $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hello I have met a question:
Find an order in $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ and verify your claim
I was thinking to use ($x_1$, $x_2$) $\prec$ ($y_1$, $y_2$) if $x_1x_2$ < $y_1y_2$, but seems it doesn't work since we can't compare if $x_1x_2$ = $y_1y_2$.

Comment: Consider lexicographic order.

Comment: As you seem to have found, your $\prec$ has the problem of not ordering $(2,3)$ and $(1,6)$, which are not the same things.  It would also have issues with $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$.  So perhaps you could extend it to something like $(x_1,x_2) \prec (y_1,y_2)$ if $x_1x_2<y_1y_2$, or if $x_1x_2=y_1y_2$ and $x_1 \lt x_2$, or if $x_1=x_2=0$ and $y_1 \lt y_2$.  You would need to check that this has the properties of an order